# Context menu in windows 8 using Popup

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Hi I am trying to create a context menu in windows 8 using Popup. On Right click of a button I am calling the following function

```
private async void UIElement_OnRightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PopupMenu popUpMenu = new PopupMenu();
        popUpMenu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("File"));
        Rect rect = GetRect(sender);
        var result= await popUpMenu.ShowForSelectionAsync(rect, Placement.Right);
    }
```

While defination for GetRect method is as follows:-

```
private Rect GetRect(object sender)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        GeneralTransform elementTransform = element.TransformToVisual(null);
        Point point = elementTransform.TransformPoint(new Point());
        Size size = new Size(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);
        Rect rect = new Rect(point, size);
        return rect;
    }
```

Though the GetRect is returning correct value, but still i am getting result as null.

Please help

Comment: I dont know why when i run it without debugging, this works fine

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why you have this problems. On the first view, everything looks fine.

Maybe Tim Heuer [Callisto](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0526563b-7a48-4b17-a087-a35cea701052) package contains an easier approach for exactly what you want. See [this](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/wiki/Flyout) example.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not clicking on the File command, but instead clicking elsewhere on the page.